# Forward /dev/input/js0 from control station to robot

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, joystick, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am forwarding joystick events from a control station to an on-board computer running ROS.
Is there a way for me to write the events to a file similar to the /dev/input/js0 file so that ROS Joy can utilize it?
If so, what format must I make the contents of the file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282842/forward-/dev/input/js0-from-control-station-to-robot/) by [slippers1_uis](https://answers.ros.org/users/32905/slippers1_uis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
May I suggest a title change? Your current question title suggests a completely off-topic question, but the body text actually asks about how to either make `joy_node` open a 'remote' joystick, or how to provide `joy_node` with data coming from a remote location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way for me to write the events to a file similar to the /dev/input/js0 file so that ROS Joy can utilize it?

yes: keep the binary format that you read from `/dev/input/js0` and use something like `uinput` to inject it into the kernel of your control station. Alernatively use `socat` (or a similar tool) to pipe `/dev/input/js0` (on your control station) to a socket on your on-board PC (similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201757)). Then have `joy` open that socket instead of an actual device.

Other than that I would say you have two options:

1. publish `Joy` msgs on your control station and subscribe those on your on-board pc
2. use a custom node running on your on-board pc, that, through a custom protocol, gets joystick event data and then publishes it as `Joy` msgs there

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [slippers1_uis](https://answers.ros.org/users/32905/slippers1_uis/) on 2018-02-15**:
This is helpful. Will try.